# summing up number on offline html

Tags: jquery, jquery-calculation

I have a huge html file 66 MB which I have no enough power to even open it in spreadsheet.
one column have to be sum up to get the lump sum.
I copy & paste a js code to do a calculation, but it doesn't work.
Could someone help me work? point out the bug.
firebug show no error

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var total_figure = 0;
            $("td.aws_figure").each(function() {
                total_figure += parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
            });
            $("label#total").html(total_figure);
            console.log(total_figure);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) please.

Comment: where is your html code ? And what console error you are getting?

Comment: you are using html5 or less than html5 verison?

Comment: Your first script tag needs a closing `</script>`.

Answer (score 0):

Close script tag like this. `Script tag is not a self closable tag`.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, you save me from hell.